# Craft CMS: sending email after entry is published

Tags: email, yii, craftcms

I want to create a site with a channel. On this channel, I want to post activities. Inside the entry, there will be a category selectable with an email address within. Once I publish the entry, craft should send an email to the email of the selected category with the details of the entry (like an info mail "hey, there is a new activity. have a look).

I googled and searched for hours, but I couldn't find a suitable solution. I stepped over craft modules, but I am new to programming and the explanations are pretty overwhelming. Is there anyone who can help me and would walk me step by step through creating such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Modules are indeed the way to go. They allow you to write custom code to extend Craft CMS functionality.

What you want can be achieved with the help of events: Craft CMS dispatches a lot of events at various points in the lifecycle of every request. You can listen to these events to react accordingly.

In your case, you should have a look to the `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` of the `craft\elements\Entry` class. To help you get started, Craft provides an [event listener code generator](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator).

You then need to write a module that includes the generated code. This [article from the Craft knowledge base](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/custom-module-events) should help you. This [article from NYStudio107](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module) is also a nice introduction.

There's a [discord community for Craft CMS](https://discord.com/invite/uuDFCTX) where you can ask for help as well as a dedicated [stackexchange site](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/).

If you need more help here, we'll need to see some code.